# Rails CDN on Google Cloud Platform with custom Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cdn

I would like to use CDN on Rails. Currently I'm running the backend on the Google Cloud Platform.

```
# Serve static files from the `/public` folder by default.
# Consider using a CDN for better performance
config.serve_static_files = true
```

I found this on config/environments/production.rb

How I can implement that?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: This got me there: https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a HTTP(S) Load Balancer? If so, you just need to enable Cloud CDN on your backend.

This is the official documentation to get started: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/quickstart

Comment: So I dont need to do on Rails side?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Unless you want to serve from a different domain, for example: cdn.yourdomain.com

If so, follow this guide: http://www.speedawarenessmonth.com/speeding-up-asset-delivery-from-your-rails-app/

You will also need to configure your HTTP(S) Load Balancer to respond to that subdomain. However, since the Google HTTP(S) Load Balancer already implements HTTP/2, you won't see much benefit from this.

Comment: Yes I want that because I have a custom domain

Comment: I think in that case you need to update your question with your requirements, because as it stands your question is answered :)

Comment: I did that now :)

Comment: What is "custom domain"? Is it a totally new domain? Or is it a subdomain of your main domain? Seriously, the more information you provide the faster, and better, someone can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133587/discussion-between-bilalreffas-and-shane-ogrady).